# how to start new activity for share action from CardView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to give the user the option to share cardview content.
i use this code in the main activity and it is working fine:

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "some text to share";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

but when i use the same code from recyclerview i get error and the application crashed.
also i modified the code by adding FLAG and still not working

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = " teext to be shared";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

iam getting this error:

Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

```
    holder.iconFavorites_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

// iam calling the code here and this block of code is located inside adapter class for recycleview .... the code located inside onBindViewHolder mithod
            }
        });

any body have solution for this problem ? if any information needed just tell me

Comment: Post the error trace.

Comment: You need to understand that every line of code may look OK on its own. The problems, usually, arise when you mix these lines to make some logical process. From information you have given it is not possible to help you. Post the code to show how you are implementing share action in RecyclerView

Comment: How do you expect people to help you when you didnt post any error or anything related to app crash?

Comment: I am not expert in android programming and I thought the information I provided is enough. –  any way i updated the question with some more details to help people understand the problem exacltly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to start an activity outside of another activity, you must use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag for the intent (as you posted).

You would set this via `sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: Then post your stacktrace. This will resolve the issue of setting the new flag. If this is not fixing the issue you are having, then you are not having an issue with this, but something else.